# Issue with angular 2 async validators array: async validator always returns validation error

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have an issue with my usage of angular 2 async validators.

I have the following component:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './send-activation-information.component.html'
})
export class SendActivationInformationComponent implements OnInit {

  activationInformationForm: FormGroup;
  submitted: boolean = false;  

  constructor(private userAccountService: UserAccountService,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activationInformationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(AppConstants.EMAIL_PATTERN)
      ], [
        validateEmailKnownFactory(this.userAccountService),
        validateUserAccountNonActivatedFactory(this.userAccountService)
      ]]
    });
  }

  sendActivationInformation() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.activationInformationForm.valid) {     
        this.userAccountService.sendActivationInformation(this.activationInformationForm.value)
        .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/sendactivationinformation/success']));
    }
  }
}
```

which uses two sync validators and two async validators specified in two arrays.

For some reason the following async validator **always indicates a validation error**:

```
export function validateUserAccountNonActivatedFactory(userAccountService: UserAccountService): {[key: string]: any} {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    return userAccountService.userAccountAlreadyActivated(control.value)
      .map(alreadyActivated => alreadyActivated ? {userAccountNonActivatedValidator: {alreadyActivated: true}} : null);
  };
}
```

...whether or not the backend call returns `false` or `true`.

FYI, `userAccountAlreadyActivated` does a http call to the backend as follows:

```
  userAccountAlreadyActivated(email: string) {
    let body = 'email=' + email;
    return this.http.get(this.urls.USER_ACCOUNT.ALREADY_ACTIVATED + body);
  }
```

Comment: I am suspecting the issue is related to the way I specify the async validator array but I am not sure.

Comment: Does it work if you only add the async validators or even only one async validator?

Comment: No. You're right the validator does not work on its own (I have commented the first validator). And it is in error whether or not `true` or `false` is returned from the backend...

Comment: Have you tried to call the validator directly like `var f = validateUserAccountNonActivatedFactory(this.userAccountService); f(someControl).subscribe(val => console.log(val));` just for debugging purposes?

Comment: Can you guarantee that this is a async-related thing? I have the same problem with non-async arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769431/angular2-form-validation-model-driven-form-broken-after-update
Also, what angular version are you using? I'm on 2.4.4.

Comment: It looks like condition for null is never met, try `map(alreadyActivated => null`) and see if it is valid

Comment: Sorry to all. It was a stupid late-evening mistake: I had forgotten to map the result to json...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had **forgotten to map the result to json**...

Thus, changing from:

```
  userAccountAlreadyActivated(email: string) {
    let body = 'email=' + email;
    return this.http.get(this.urls.USER_ACCOUNT.ALREADY_ACTIVATED + body);
  }
```

to:

```
  userAccountAlreadyActivated(email: string) {
    let body = 'email=' + email;
    return this.http.get(this.urls.USER_ACCOUNT.ALREADY_ACTIVATED + body).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

fixed the issue - which had nothing to do with angular validators per say.